# Should I include marginally better results in a writing sample?

Tags: publications, machine-learning

I am performing some experiments and my results are only marginally better than the current state-of-the-art, 0.12% increase in accuracy but on the far side of 90's. Should I include the said SOTA model for comparison saying 0.12 is significant given SOTA accuracy is 97% or should I not include this model in the comparison results.

I, unfortunately, do not have the SOTA model or its weights to run any kind of tests for more insights to write in the paper.

Comment: A writing sample for what, exactly?

Comment: A marginal improvement like this is most likely just an effect of implicit overfitting ( I assume you're talking about machine learning? )

Answer (score 3):

Because you mentioned that

> I, unfortunately, do not have the SOTA model or its weights to run any
> kind of tests for more insights to write in the paper.

If you also did not use the same dataset that was used to validate the SOTA model, in my opinion, your conclusion is invalid and should not be included in the writing sample(?).

Also, you should compare both models using different datasets to evaluate the overall performance.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question asked.

Comment: I edited my answer. It should be clearer now.